# How to use mouse to rotate matplotlib 3D plots in wxPython?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

Here is a snippet of code I use to display a 2D matplotlib plot in a wxPython application:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import wx

[wxPython application and class code snipped]

    figure = Figure()
    axes = figure.add_subplot(111)
    canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self, wx.ID_ANY, figure)
    plotSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    plotSizer.Add(self, canvas, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
    plotPanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=DEFAULT_PLOT_SIZE)
    plotPanel.SetSizer(plotSizer)
```

I can plot to the axes, redraw the canvas and pan and zoom.  When I try to do the equivalent using 3D, the 3D plot is displayed, but I can't rotate/pan/zoom.  The only difference in this code is the additional import for 3D and addition of projection parameter to add_subplot().

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import wx

[wxPython application and class code snipped]

    figure = Figure()
    axes = figure.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
    canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self, wx.ID_ANY, figure)
    plotSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    plotSizer.Add(self, canvas, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
    plotPanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=DEFAULT_PLOT_SIZE)
    plotPanel.SetSizer(plotSizer)
```

I get this warning:

```
...\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py:1009: UserWarning: Axes3D.figure.canvas is 'None', mouse rotation disabled.  Set canvas then call Axes3D.mouse_init().
```

So I tried setting Axes3D.figure.canvas with this code after the call to FigureCanvasWxAgg():

```
axes.figure.canvas = canvas
axes.mouse_init()
```

But this doesn't work; I still can't use the mouse to rotate the 3D plot.

The demo source code at http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html that uses stand-alone matplotlib work; I can use the mouse to rotate the plots there.  How can I get mouse rotation working when using wxPython?

Comment: Can you give a small runnable sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I just had to swap the order of the canvas and axes creation. The canvas should be created and added to the figure first, then the 3D axes can be created.

```
figure = Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self, wx.ID_ANY, figure)
axes = figure.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
plotSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
plotSizer.Add(self, canvas, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
plotPanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=DEFAULT_PLOT_SIZE)
plotPanel.SetSizer(plotSizer)
```

Comment: You should really instantiate panel before the canvas and add the canvas to the panel: